# Creating Plots for a Family of Solutions

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I am wondering how do you set the parameters appropriately for $a_n,\,\alpha,\,\text{and }b_n$ to plot the family of solution of:

> $u_n(r,t) = [a_n\cos(k_n\alpha t)+b_n\sin(k_n\alpha t)]J_0(k_nr)$

where the Bessel function of the first kind of zero order represents $J_0.$

$0<k_1<k_2<\ldots<k_n<\ldots$ are all positve zeros of $J_0$.

The original equation is: $u_{tt}=\alpha(u_{rr}+\tfrac{1}{r}u_r), \quad 0<r<1,~ t>0,$

$u(1,t)=0, \qquad t>0,$

$u(r,t)$ remain finite as $r\rightarrow 0^+,$

$u(r,0)=f(r), \qquad 0<r<1,$

$u_t(r,0)=g(r), \qquad 0<r<1,~~$ where $f,g$ are initial displacement and velocities.

I tried something of the type:

> ```
> 0<r<1;
> t>0;
> Plot3D[Cos[8.654 t] + Sin[8.654 t] BesselJ[0, 8.654 r], {r, 0, 1}, {t,0, 10}]
> ```

Choosing other parameters in the solution to have the value of 1.

The output would resemble the following:

[image: vm]

First graphic is for $J_0(2.4r)$,
Second graphic is for $J_0(5.5r)$,
and Third graphic is for $J_0(8.7r)$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you have some sort of time evolution of Bessel-like waves. I also see that your examples deal with 3rd zero of Bessel J0 - I'll use it too. Define a function:

```
mYf[r_, t_, n_] := With[
    {k = BesselJZero[0, n]}, 
    (Cos[k t] + Sin[k t]) BesselJ[0, k r]
]
```

Build a time evolution list:

```
giflist = Table[
    RevolutionPlot3D[
        Evaluate[N@mYf[r, t, 3]],
        {r, 0, 1}, 
        SphericalRegion -> True,
        PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
        ImageSize -> 450,
        PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7],
        ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
        MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5],
        PlotLabel -> time == t
    ], 
    {t, 0, 2 Pi/N[BesselJZero[0, 3]], .05}
];
```

Display as animated .GIF -

```
Export["bessel.gif", giflist]
```

[image]

Display as a table:

```
GraphicsGrid[
    Partition[
        Show[#,Boxed ->False, Axes -> False] & /@ giflist,
        5
    ], 
    ImageSize -> 500,
    Spacings -> 0
]
```

[image]

Create an interface to investigate parameters. You BTW did not define dependence of `a` and `b` on `n` so I'll just define them generically:

```
Manipulate[
    RevolutionPlot3D[
        Evaluate[N@mYf[r, t, n, a, b, α]],
        {r, 0, 1},
        SphericalRegion -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
        ImageSize -> 350,
        PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7],
        ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
        MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5],
        PlotLabel -> time == t,
        PlotPoints -> 25
    ], 
    {{t, 1.36, "time"}, 0, 2, ImageSize -> Tiny},
    Delimiter,
    "zero's order", 
    {{n, 7, ""}, Range[7], SetterBar, ImageSize -> Tiny},
    Delimiter,
    {{a, 1.2, "a_n"}, 0, 2, ImageSize -> Tiny},
    {{b, 1, "b_n"}, 0, 2, ImageSize -> Tiny},
    {{α, .9, "α"}, 0, 2, ImageSize -> Tiny},
    FrameMargins -> 0,
    ImageMargins -> 0, 
    ControlPlacement -> Left, 
    Initialization :> (
        mYf[r_, t_, n_, a_, b_, α_] := 
            With[
                {k =  BesselJZero[0, n]},
                (a Cos[α k t] + 
                  b Sin[α k t]) *
                  BesselJ[0, k r]
            ]
    )
]
```

[image]

Comment: +1...Vitaliy, brilliant!! Honestly, this is some nice work. You must got good at this fast or been using mathematica for some time. Thanks, I did not have any information on `a,b, or n` so thanks for just making some assumptions on them.

Comment: One comment though. When I export the function to a graphic `.gif` the animation does not show. Only output is: `bessel.gif`. Any ideas?

Comment: @nightowl You're welcome ;) GIF won't show in your notebook. GIF is saved to a default location (My Documents on Windows) if only file name is mentioned in in "..." inside `Export` function. You can put there the whole directory/file path to where you want to save GIF. Use menu **Insert >> File Path...**. Read more here: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you want to plot a family of functions $f_{a,\,b,\,c}(x)=a\sin(b\,x^c)$ for $a\in\{-2,-1,1,2\}$, $b\in\{1,2\}$, $c\in\{1,2,3\}$:

```
(* Define the function itself *)
f[x_, a_, b_, c_] := a Sin[b x^c]

(* Generate a table consisting of all possible
   combinations for the values of a, b, c *)
fPlot = Table[
    f[#, a, b, c],
    {a, {-2, -1, 1, 2}},
    {b, 1, 2},
    {c, 1, 3}
];

(* Flatten it so it's a 2-dimensional list that
   can be plotted as usual *)
fPlot = Flatten[#, 1] & @ fPlot;

(* Convert it to a function, making use of the "#"
   introduced in the Table statement above *)
fPlot = Function[Evaluate@fPlot];

(* Plot it *)
Plot[fPlot[x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 3}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks David for the general idea of creating families of graphs.

Comment: some corrections though. I think $c \in {1,2,3}$ where as in the code you have ${c,1,3}$. Next would be, you said make use of the `#` to make it into a function, but I only see the `@` being used in the section of code. Is this what you meant? Overall, nice implementation.

Comment: **1.** `{c,1,3}` loops from 1 to 3, which is equivalent to `{c,{1,2,3}}`.

Comment: **2.** Using `#` is completely independent of anything, it's simply short notation for `Slot[1]`. You can for example write `#^2&[2]` and it will work; `@x` is simply a shortcut for `[x]`. In my solution, I used `#` as short for `Slot[1]` without making a function out of it initially. The reason for this is that `Function` has the attribute `HoldAll`, which would have required me to use `Evaluate` in each step involving some transformation of the function body. The way I did it was manipulating the whole thing first, and then making a function out of it at the very end.